# I am having trouble looking into a list to see if something exists otherwise add it to the list

Tags: python, list

So I am having trouble with one part of my program which is supposed to get the users input, see if it exists a list named "clues". If not, it should add it to the list and if it does already exist in the list, an error message should be printed.

The piece of code so far is shown below...

```
#PROCEDURE FOR ADDING A NEW PAIRING
def add_pairing(clues):
    addClue = False
#USER INPUTS A LETTER AND SYMBOL
    letter=input("What letter would you like to add?  ").upper()

    symbol=input("\nWhat symbol would you like to pair with  ").upper()
    userInput= letter + symbol
#GOES THROUGH CLUES TO SEE IF THE PAIRING HAS ALREADY BEEN ENTERED
    for clue in clues:
#IF THE CLUE HAS ALREADY BEEN ADDED, IT WILL PRINT A MESSAGE        
        if letter in clues:
            print("The letter either doesn't exist or has already been entered ")
            break
        elif symbol in clues:
            print("The letter either doesn't exist or has already been entered")

        elif len(userInput) ==1:
            print("You can only enter one character")

#IF THE CLUE DOESN'T EXIST IN CLUES, IT WILL GO TO THE else STATEMENT       
        else:
            newClue = letter + symbol
            addClue = True
    if addClue == True:
        clues.append(newClue)
    #PRINTS MESSAGE SAYING THAT THE PAIRING HAS BEEN ADDED
        print("The pairing has been added")
#PRINTS CLUES AFTER THE PAIRING HAS BEEN ADDED
        print (clues)
    return clues
```

When I run the program and select the option to add a pairing the outcome is shown below...

```
What letter would you like to add?  a

What symbol would you like to pair with  #
The pairing has been added
['A#', 'M*', 'N', 'A#']
```

The problem is that where I have entered 'a#' it has still added it to the list of clues despite the paring already existing there...

The correct outcome should be as shown below...

```
What letter would you like to add?  a

What symbol would you like to pair with  #
The pairing already exists in list of clues
['A#', 'M*', 'N',]
```

I am calling add_pairing from a menu...

```
 --- ENTER THE NUMBER TO GO TO THAT OPTION ---

0 - QUIT
1 - ADD A LETTER AND SYMBOL PAIRING
2 - DELETE A PAIRING
3 - DISPLAY CLUES SO FAR
4 - CHECK YOUR GUESSES WITH THE REAL VERSION
5 - CALCULATE THE FREQUENCY

"""
)
```

The code for the add_pairing function in the menu is as follows..

```
elif choice == "1":
    add_pairing(clues)
```

Code for checking the users clues with the correct clues...

```
#PROCEDURE FOR CHECKING WITH SOLVED FILE
def check_clues():
count = 0
# TRIES TO OPEN FILE SOLVED.TXT
try:
    with open('solved.txt') as r:
# READS THROUGH ALL THE LINES IN SOLVED.TXT
         solved = r.readlines()
# WILL DISPLAY AN ERROR MESSAGE IF SOLVED.TXT IS NOT FOUND
except:
    print("Error finding file")
# WILL TRY AND OPEN THE FILE 'clues.txt'
try:
    with open('clues.txt') as r: 
         pairings = r.readlines()
except:
    print("Error finding ")


# GOES THROUGH BOTH THE USERS CLUES AND SOLVED.TXT TO SEE HOW MANY PAIRINGS ARE THE SAME
for solve in solved:
    for user in pairings:
        if pairings in solved:
             count =+ 1
# Prints the amount of clues the user got right out of 10
print('You got:', count, 'out of', len(solved), 'correct!')
```

Solved.txt...

```
ACQUIRED
ALMANAC
INSULT
JOKE
HYMN
GAZELLE
AMAZON
EYEBROWS
AFFIX
VELLUM
```

Clues.txt...

```
A#
M*
N%
```

However more pairings can be added to this....

Comment: How are you calling `add_pairing`? I tried calling it with an empty list and it didn't print "The pairing has been added".

Comment: I am calling add_pairing from a menu which the user enters a number to go to the specific option....

Comment: I have added it to the end of my program...

Comment: Hint: `'A' in ['A#', 'M*', 'N']` returns False, even though 'A' is part of one of the strings in the list.

Comment: OK so what would I need to do?

Comment: Do you need to preserve ordering? If not, you'd get much better performance from a `set` than a `list`; `if x in my_list` is O(n) -- it gets slower as the list gets longer -- whereas `if x in my_set` is constant-time; it performs the same way no matter how many items are in the set.

Answer (score 1):

You must change the line `if letter in clues:` to `if userInput in clues:` because you nust check the exist of `userInput` in your array

Also you dont need `for clue in clues:` when you write `if letter in clues:` python interpreter search over your array itself !

so your code must be like this :

```
#PROCEDURE FOR ADDING A NEW PAIRING
def add_pairing(clues):
    addClue = False
#USER INPUTS A LETTER AND SYMBOL
    letter=input("What letter would you like to add?  ").upper()

    symbol=input("\nWhat symbol would you like to pair with  ").upper()
    userInput= letter + symbol
#GOES THROUGH CLUES TO SEE IF THE PAIRING HAS ALREADY BEEN ENTERED
#IF THE CLUE HAS ALREADY BEEN ADDED, IT WILL PRINT A MESSAGE        
    if userInput in clues:
            print("The letter either doesn't exist or has already been entered ")
    elif len(userInput) ==1:
            print("You can only enter one character")

#IF THE CLUE DOESN'T EXIST IN CLUES, IT WILL GO TO THE else STATEMENT       
    else:
            newClue = letter + symbol
            addClue = True
    if addClue == True:
        clues.append(newClue)
    #PRINTS MESSAGE SAYING THAT THE PAIRING HAS BEEN ADDED
        print("The pairing has been added")
#PRINTS CLUES AFTER THE PAIRING HAS BEEN ADDED
        print (clues)
    return clues
```

Edit:
change your checking commands to this :

```
for user in pairings:
     if user in solved:
           count =+ 1
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to like the break after print("The letter either doesn't exist or has already been entered ")

Comment: yes you need to remove break ! when delete the `for`

Comment: It is still doing the same thing as before... Would it be easier if I post all of my code?

Comment: There are already 3 clues to help the user out which are read in from an external file at the beginning of the program....

Comment: why you add upper to your symbol?

Comment: To be honest there is no real point... That can be taken out... It will only need upper at the end of letter...

Comment: hey i find the error you need to check `userInput` not `letter`

Comment: OK great ! Could put this in the answer?

Comment: There is also one more issue in my program, would you be able to help me solve that?

Comment: OK so another option in my program is for the user to check the amount of clues they got correct with the real version.

Comment: The problem which is happening is that when the user wants to check to see how many clues they got correct, it keeps on saying  " You got 0 out of 10 correct" even though I know some of them which I have added are correct...

Comment: whats the solved and pairings content ? can you add some of them to your question/

Comment: you syntax is incorrect for checking ! i will add another to my answer !

Comment: because i have not all of your code ! i cant say any thing and it seems that it is not a big problem and you can figure it out easily ! so i suggest read your code again and find the problem

Comment: There, I have added the two files to the end of my question which are necessary for checking the clues with the correct version...